# Encapsulating game object in class

Tags: c++, ogre

In my attempt to create my first 3D game using Ogre I started writing a general "Object" class.
The constructor:

```
Object( const char* mesh, Ogre::SceneManager*& sm )
{
    ...
    _sn = sm->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode( _sn_name );
    _ent = sm->createEntity( _ent_name, mesh );
    _sn->attachObject(_ent);
    ...            
}
```

_sn being a SceneNode* and _ent an Entity* (both private).
The problem is that nothing gets drawn to the screen!
But if I use:

```
Ogre::Entity *map = mSceneMgr->createEntity("map","map.mesh");
Ogre::SceneNode *sc = mSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode("mapNode");
sc->attachObject(map);
```

outside of a class, the object gets drawn and everything works.

What's wrong with my approach and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using pointer reference as parameter? Any particular reason to do so?

Comment: In order to avoid an unnecessary copy(?).Tried using simple pointer/refference, doesn't work.

Comment: So you did it poorly/wrong. Either option avoids copying, you certainly don't need both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this.
In my destructor I had the scene manager call detachAllObjects(). Commenting/removing that solved the problem obviously

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution : i have same experience before it, You should check:

1. How many instance created?
2. How many constructor are here?
3. Do you use this  word ? if your class inherited, careful to applying parent methods and attributes , because they are depend on their constructor and may be return null pointer.
4. If you use inheritance , i preferred to pass parent obj to inherited class.

Comment: Only 1 instance, 1 constructor, no inheritance